# Unable to connect Tata photon plus Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I am not able to connect my tata photon plus in Ubuntu 12.04.

I have already used these commands

```
sudo mkdir /media/modem
sudo mount /dev/sr1 /media/modem
```

but I could not get any file inside `/modem` folder

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Does your Photon Plus have a Linux installation folder?

Answer (score 0):

Connect with wifi or some other source and install `wvdial`

after this run `wvdialconf` Check the output carefully as line `Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2` would come from its output.

And in `/etc/wvdial.conf`

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2 
Phone = #777
Username = internet
Password = internet
New PPPD = yes
stupid Mode = 1
```

**Again**: please check `Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2` line as it should be same which is indicated in `wvdialconf` output after connecting the tataphone plus(Any provider)

Then `wvdial` to connect to internet.

depending on your systen use of `sudo` might be required.